What is attacking my lemon queen sunflowers?
My Lemon Queen Sunflowers were doing good, but some insects and/or disease has attacked them. Little white bugs on the leaves and some strange matter that doesn't look good.  Any suggestions?
I live in Tucson, AZ so it gets pretty hot, though so far it has been in the high 80s low 90s at the highest and they have been doing good.

